# How to write a hack for Opera 12 on the stylus?

Tags: stylus

Good afternoon!
It became necessary to write on the stylus hack for Opera 12 using doesnotexist: -o-prefocus, .selector

There is such code:

```
.class-name 
    background url('my.svg') no-repeat
    background-size contain

    .svg_no &
       &.icon_size
            &_16
                background url('my_size_16.png') no-repeat
            &_32
                background url('my_size_32.png') no-repeat
            &_56
                background url('my_size_56.png') no-repeat
```

is now in:

```
.class-name {
  background: url("my.svg") no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
.svg_no .class-name.icon_size_16 {
   background: url("my_size_16.png") no-repeat;
}
.svg_no .class-name.icon_size_32 {
   background: url("my_size_32.png") no-repeat;
}
.svg_no .class-name.icon_size_56 {
  background: url("my_size_56.png") no-repeat;
}
```

How do I add this line "doesnotexist: -o-prefocus, .selector", that would get:

```
.class-name {
  background: url("my.svg") no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
doesnotexist:-o-prefocus, .class-name.icon_size_16,
.svg_no .class-name.icon_size_16 {
   background: url("my_size_16.png") no-repeat;
}
doesnotexist:-o-prefocus, .class-name.icon_size_32,
.svg_no .class-name.icon_size_32 {
   background: url("my_size_32.png") no-repeat;
}
doesnotexist:-o-prefocus, .class-name.icon_size_56,
.svg_no .class-name.icon_size_56 {
    background: url("my_size_56.png") no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
.class-name
    background url('my.svg') no-repeat
    background-size contain

    &.icon_size
        &_16
            /doesnotexist:-o-prefocus
            &
            .svg_no &
                background url('my_size_16.png') no-repeat
        &_32
            /doesnotexist:-o-prefocus
            &
            .svg_no &
                background url('my_size_32.png') no-repeat
        &_56
            /doesnotexist:-o-prefocus
            &
            .svg_no &
                background url('my_size_56.png') no-repeat
```